# Training a classifier with Textblob from csv in python - encoding issues

Tags: python, csv, text, encoding, textblob

I am trying to train a classifier with Textblob by loading my training set from a CSV file. The text in the CSV should be in UTF-8.
When I try to run my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
with open('trainingset.csv', 'r') as fp:
   cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 31:    invalid start byte
```

However, it seems that Texblob is using UTF-8 to encode the CSV (I took a look at the source code for the CSV opener, which can be found [here)](http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/textblob/formats.html).

So I really can't understand why I am getting this error. Any help to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following line at the start of your python file

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I actually have it. Sorry for not having reported it.